# How to find the value(s) of K when K^2+2k+15 is equal to -9k + 1

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve the following question, where I am to: [image]

is continuous at x = -1.

I have made the following steps:

```
1) Substitute -1 for all X values, which gives k^2+2k+15 if x<-1, and -9k+1 if x>=-1.
2) If the parameter is continuous, both functions must be equal to each other. So k^2+2k+15 is equal to -9k+1.
3) Move everything to one side --> k^2+9k+2k+15-1, which is equal to k^2+11k+14.
4) This is the step I get stuck on. For I have not been able to factor this without using the quadratic formula. Which is (-11+sqrt(65))/2 and (-11-sqrt(65))/2.
```

Could anyone please show me where I went wrong here?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your calculation in 1) is wrong: $$(-1+k)^2+{-2k-14\over -1}=k^2+15.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your calculations on the first equation. If $x \rightarrow -1$, then $$(x + k)^2 + \dfrac{-2k -14}{x} \rightarrow$$$$ (k - 1)^2 +2k +14 \rightarrow$$ $$k^2 -2k + 1 +2k +14 \rightarrow$$$$ k^2 + 15$$